# Date as Type: type and determining time left

Tags: python, date, datetime

An API I am working with returns and end_date attribute of type: type. It's formatted like this: u'2013-04-15 14:00:00'. I simply want to subtract today -- datetime.date(2013, 4, 9) -- from whatever the end_date is to determine the time remaining. I have looked through the documentation for the python Datetime module, but I haven't been able to figure out how to take the end_date attribute and convert it into something I can use to subtract today from. Am I missing something in the library? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date_a = datetime.strptime('2013-04-15 14:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date_b = datetime.strptime('2013-04-15 14:02:05','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

elapsed_time = date_b - date_a
```

then: `print elapsed_time.total_seconds()` will return 125 seconds. my `elapsed_time` is of timedelta type. For example elapsed_time.days could also give you the number of days.

`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` is the format given for the date parser. [Check Python doc for strptime format in the paragraph 8.1.7. strftime() and strptime() Behavior.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: I think the format should be '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'.  You're missing the colons between the hours, minutes, and seconds.  You'll get a ValueError if you try parsing the string with that format.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that when I was playing with this in the shell. Thanks thought, this works perfect and helps me do exactly what I want!